# C# 6 null conditional operator does not work for LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, roslyn

I expected this to work, but apparently the way the IL generates, it throws `NullReferenceException`. Why can't the compiler generate similar code for queries?

In the `ThisWorks` case, the compiler generates code that short circuits the rest of the expression, why can't it do the same thing for LINQ query case?

```
class Target
{
    public ChildTarget Child;
}

class ChildTarget
{
    public int[] Values;
}

IEnumerable<int> ThisWorks(Target target) =>
    target.Child?.Values.Select(x => x);

IEnumerable<int> ThisDoesNotWork(Target target) =>
    from x in target.Child?.Values select x;

ThisWorks(new Target());
ThisDoesNotWork(new Target()); // this throws NullReferenceException
```

Decompiled results

```
private static IEnumerable<int> ThisDoesNotWork(Target target)
{
    ChildTarget child = target.Child;
    IEnumerable<int> values = (child != null) ? child.Values : null;
    Func<int, int> func;
    if ((func = Program._func) == null)
    {
        func = (Program._func = new Func<int, int>(Program._funcMethod));
    }
    return values.Select(func);
}

private static IEnumerable<int> ThisWorks(Target target)
{
    ChildTarget child = target.Child;
    IEnumerable<int> values;
    if (child == null)
    {
        values = null;
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<int> values = child.Values;
        Func<int, int> func;
        if ((func = Program._func2) == null)
        {
            func = (Program._func2= new Func<int, int>(Program._funcMethod2));
        }
        values = values.Select(func);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the compiler translates the null conditional operator first before it translates the query syntax.  So your query is like `(Child == null ? null : Child.Values).Select(x => x)`.  Had it translated the query syntax to method syntax first it would have worked.

Comment: Why would you expect it to behave any differently? In your example, `target.Child?.Values` evaluates to `null`. The null conditional only affects the expression it is a part of. You're effectively doing `null.Select(...)`.

Comment: @JeffMercado  I expect `from x in e?.Value select x` to be `e?.Value.Select(x =x>)`  *since* the later expression *works* this is the surprise. As @Neal pointed out, it's the subtle bracketing that is to blame, as well as the order of transformations too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is in the C# language specification, which says

> A query expression of the form
>
> > from *x* in *e* select *x*
>
> is translated into
>
> > ( *e* ) . Select ( *x* => *x* )

Note the parentheses around *e* in the last line. That shows clearly that the null-conditional expression (in your example) ends before Select is called, which means Select might be called with the resulting null.

Why can't it do the same thing for Linq? Because that's not the way the feature was designed to work. The specification for the null-conditional operators do not have a special case for queries, nor vice versa.

Comment: I was planning on finding the specification for the null conditional operator to complete this explanation, only to find there was none. Now will have to spend some time parsing this thread to figure out what happened: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883

Comment: Also confirmed this `(target.Child?.Values).Select(x => x)` also throws, as expected.